# Timeout configuration for global and per producer/consumer specific in camel

Tags: apache-camel

I'm new here (it's my first question).
I would like to configure a timeout so if one of the endpoint on the route takes longer camel will throw an exception or will provide control otherwise.
It seems that such an issue was considered in the past:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-1661?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#issue-tabs

I wonder if a simple interceptor (e.g. one that will wrap the endpoint with multicast with a timeout) may do the job, or what are the problems with this of approach (ofcourse a real solution will do it lighter than using multicast, but the same idea).

Thanks, 
Sagi

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do it "lighter" than with the multicast. It certainly is not very flexible in error handling if you have a bunch of different endpoints.

The main issue is that there are differences between components and how they behave.

From the [mulicast docs](http://camel.apache.org/multicast):

> If the timeout is reached with running tasks still remaining, certain
>   tasks for which it is difficult for Camel to shut down in a graceful
>   manner may continue to run. So use this option with a bit of care.

I suggest you try out your specific scenario with the endpoints you are using and test it fully.

An other option would be to post a specific case here for suggestions from SO users.